# Error Trying To Run Excel Macros Via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm a data analyst with some very restricted access to a company terminal, I'm trying to automate the some manual processes of refreshing some excels via macros, however the template code I sourced online is throwing the below **Error**:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIH9O.png)

**Code For Reference:**

```
# start Excel 
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application  
#open file 
$FilePath = '\\pvbfilr0002\Publishing\Collections\Collections Analytics All\SQL Code\Matt\2021 Projects\Daily Trading Report\Archive Version\DailyTradingReportPWS.xlsm' #<------- Change this!!! 
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)  

#make it visible (just to check what is happening) 
$excel.Visible = $true  

# macro name to run
#$Macro = "Refresh"
#$Macro1 = "TopTable"
#$Macro2 = "Save"

#access the Application object and run a macro $app = $excel.Application 
$app.Run('Refresh', 'TopTable', 'Save')
#$excel.Quit()     

#Popup box to show completion
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell $wshell.Popup("Operation Completed",0,"Done",0x1)
```

My experience with Powershell is limited so apologies if I'm asking simple questions.

Comment: So, where did you define variable `$app` ? I think that should be `$excel.Run('Refresh')`. Also you need three of those lines if you want to run 3 different macros. All other parameters would be parameters for the macro in the first parameter.

Comment: I think that's the issue, wasn't aware you had to define $app but I've done: $app = $excel.Application. and that solved the problem. Now just writing it up into an email. Appreciate the response, will incorporate your suggestions on dropping COM objects!#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, you have not defined variable `$app`, hence the error message about the null-valued expression.

If you want to run 3 different macros, one after the other, you will need 3 `.Run()` commands. Any second, third, etc. parameter given is handled as being parameters to the macro which is named in the first parameter.
See [Application.Run method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.run)

Change to

```
$excel.Run('Refresh')
$excel.Run('TopTable')
$excel.Run('Save')
```

Note that you should always release used COM objects from memory when done with them, so after `$excel.Quit()` add these lines:

```
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

(the same goes for the `$wshell` COM object you use for the popup)